# how to printf variable values alternatively?

Tags: matlab, printf

Here is what I want to do :

I have array

```
A = [0,1,2]
```

and array

```
B = [9,-1,97]
```

I want to do a fprintf to print value as following

```
0 9
1 -1
2 97
```

So far I have

```
formatSpec = '%.i %8.3f0\n';
fprintf(formatSpec,A,B)
```

but of course it first print A then B instead of: one value of A, one value of B, new line, one value of A... :

```
0 1
2 9
-1 97
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate `A` and `B` along the first axis :

```
fprintf(formatSpec,[A;B])
```

Comment: didn't though about doing it this way! Thanks